# Dirac measure $\delta_x$ not absolutely continuous for almost every $x$ in $[0,1]$ with respect to the Lebesgue measure $\mu$ on $[0,1]$.

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

> Show that the Dirac measure $\delta_x$ not absolutely continuous with respect to the Lebesgue measure $\mu$ on $[0,1]$ for almost every $x$ in $[0,1]$ .

I though about using $\mathbb{Q}$ as the example set. However, it lead to the following which doesn't show what I'm trying to show:

Clearly $\mu(\mathbb{Q})=0$. However, $\delta_x(\mathbb{Q})=1$ if $x\in\mathbb{Q}$ and $\delta_x(\mathbb{Q})=0$ if $x\not\in\mathbb{Q}$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\delta_x <<\mu$ fails for **every** $x$. This is because $\mu\{x\}=0$ and $\delta_x \{x\}=1$.

Comment: Makes complete sense, thank you.